# Tensorflow is not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed Tensorflow by using pip, but when I import it in python I'm getting such error.

```
2020-11-13 11:59:23.274303: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-11-13 11:59:23.274334: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29]
```

I'm not understanding why such error. Any help??

Answer (score 0):

You should install CUDA 10.1. A clear instructin about how to remove any exsiting CUDA and how to install 10.1 could be found here:
https://medium.com/@exesse/cuda-10-1-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-d04f89287130